# Why are some components in my React TS component library throwing Minified React error #321

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am building a React component library with TypeScript and webpack and I test it with `webpack serve` on a blank html page. Now the weird thing is that when I use the components like that every single component works perfectly fine. However if I want to use them in another project (install the library with npm) e. g. with a create-react-app a few throw a Minified React error #321. I have no idea why this is happening. Also I cant see a pattern in the Not-working components.

If you want to give it a try yourself: https://www.npmjs.com/package/athenic-ui

Comment: Most likely you have multiple copies of react lib in the other project. See this guide: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just looked at your repo and I think the problem `Minified React error #321` is likely from including `react`/`react-dom` into the build your library. Then having more than one React instances after consuming project getting built.

So in order to fix you would have to exclude `react`/`react-dom` as external deps where should be included at parent project level which consumes your library.

```js
// webpack.config.js
exports.module = [
  // your dev one
  // { ... },
  // your prod one
  {
    // ...
    externals: {
      react: "react",
      'react-dom': "react-dom"
    },
  }
]
```

PS: After having done above step, you might recognize your main bundle file would significantly be reduced in size as well :)